# Python networking : find MAC address for corresponding interfaces

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sockets

I has found a scripts from **pmav99**. Big thanks to him.

```
import socket
import psutil

def get_ip_addresses(family):
    for interface, snics in psutil.net_if_addrs().items():
        for snic in snics:
            if snic.family == family:
                yield (interface, snic.address, snic.netmask)

ipv4s = list(get_ip_addresses(socket.AF_INET))

print ipv4s
```

The result is :

```
[('Local Area Connection* 2', '169.254.189.147', '255.255.0.0'), ('Ethernet', '192.168.18.34', '255.255.255.0'), ('Wi-Fi', '192.168.1.102', '255.255.255.0'), ('Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1', '127.0.0.1', '255.0.0.0')]
```

But in net_if_addrs() of psutil, it also provide mac-address of each interfaces. So how can i add the mac address to the list ? the keys name of MAC address also is **address**. I can't find the way to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.net_if_addrs), MAC addresses are noted by family `psutil.AF_LINK`. This code fragment will get a list of interface names, along with the MAC addresses.

```
macs = list(get_ip_addresses(psutil.AF_LINK))
print macs
```

The following program will produce a mapping from MAC addresses to IPV4 addresses:

```
import socket
import psutil

def get_ip_addresses(family):
    for interface, snics in psutil.net_if_addrs().items():
        for snic in snics:
            if snic.family == family:
                yield (interface, (snic.address, snic.netmask))

ipv4s = dict(get_ip_addresses(socket.AF_INET))
macs = dict(get_ip_addresses(psutil.AF_LINK))
mac2ipv4 = {macs[k][0]: ipv4s[k] for k in set(macs) & set(ipv4s)}

print mac2ipv4
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, but i also need interface name too.  I find a way to do that is simply add **if** to it.
if snic.family == -1 :
 mac = snic.address
if snic.family == 2 :
 yield (interface, snic.address, snic.netmask, mac)

Comment: If you don't mind, please post your solution as an answer. Then, if you decide to use it, accept your own answer (yes, that is allowed). By posting it as an answer, future [SO] visitors may be helped.

Answer (score 3):

i find a simply way to get the result that i want

```
import socket
import psutil

def get_ip_addresses(family):
    for interface, snics in psutil.net_if_addrs().items():
        for snic in snics:
            if snic.family == -1 :
                mac = snic.address
            if snic.family == 2 :
                yield (interface, snic.address, snic.netmask, mac)

ipv4 = list(get_ip_addresses(socket.AF_INET))

print ipv4
```

and the result look like this :

```
[('Local Area Connection* 2', '169.254.189.147', '255.255.0.0', '34-F3-9A-4C-D0-C5'), ('Ethernet', '192.168.18.34', '255.255.255.0', 'C8-5B-76-AC-B7-BC'), ('Wi-Fi', '192.168.1.106', '255.255.255.0', '34-F3-9A-4C-D0-C4'), ('Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1', '127.0.0.1', '255.0.0.0', '00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0')]
```

Connection name with corresponding ipv4, netmask and mac address.
Hope it helpful for orther visitor :).