# How to fix "TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object"?

Tags: python

I am writing a simple program for linux that looks at the mac address. My program should look at "`ifconfig`" and use regular expressions to pull out only the MAC address.

```
import subprocess
import re

print('This program will only look at the mac address.')
print('Enter your interface.(for example: wlan0))')
interface = input(': ')
find_mac = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", interface], shell=True)
mac_clean = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w\:\w\w", find_mac)
print(mac_clean.group(0))`
```

I expect the output of to be `MY:MAC:ADDRESS`, but the actual output is

> mac_clean = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", find_mac)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 183, in search
>   return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
>   TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes - like object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of subprocess.check_output is bytes, and you needs a string for this to work

```py
mac_clean = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w\:\w\w", find_mac.decode())
```

You can decode the bytes with `bytes.decode`

You can also get it much easiley with `psutils` see this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49121166/python-networking-find-mac-address-for-corresponding-interfaces)

Comment: If I enter eth0 or lo, the program displays the MAC address of wlan0. How to fix it?
I put .decode()

Comment: I’m not rushing you, but please help more quickly. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

First, transform find_mac to string.

```py
find_mac = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", interface], shell=True).decode()
```

Then, for your pattern in regex.

```py
mac_clean = re.search(r"^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$", find_mac)
```

Some tutorial and documentation on regex :

- [Free course](https://wanago.io/2018/04/30/regex-course-part-one-basic-concepts/)
- [tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/regular-expressions-data-scientists/)
- [Pratical application](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/regex-was-taking-5-days-flashtext-does-it-in-15-minutes-55f04411025f/)
- [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Edit : Correct mistake based on @Reznik comment

Edit1: Fix regex

Comment: str on a byte object will return a ```b'string'```, ```decode``` is needed here

Comment: Thanks for being so fast. Could you give a link to study this material?

Comment: Yes. Thanks so much

Comment: @kali_xyyali I have updated the post with some documentation, cource, tuto.